# What is a semicolon in a makefile prerequisites list?

Tags: makefile

In one of the early sections of the GNU make manual, [Section 3.7](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html#Reading-Makefiles), there is an outline of a makefile recipe

```
immediate : immediate ; deferred
        deferred
```

involving a semicolon in the prerequisites list. So a valid recipe could be

```
output.o : output.c header1.h header2.h; header3.h
        gcc output.c -o output.o
```

What is the point of the semicolon? Since the aforementioned section talks about immediate and deferred variable expansion, I am guessing that the part up to the semicolon is expanded immediately and the part of the semicolon is expanded only once the target is executed. Can anybody confirm?

I have found similar questions on SO but those present special cases and none of the their accepted answers seem to get the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [4.2 Rule Syntax](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rule-Syntax.html#Rule-Syntax):

> In general, a rule looks like this:
>
> ```
> targets : prerequisites
>         recipe
>         …
> ```
>
> or like this:
>
> ```
> targets : prerequisites ; recipe
>         recipe
>         …
> ```

[...]

> The recipe lines start with a tab character (or the first character in the value of the `.RECIPEPREFIX` variable; see [Special Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#Special-Variables)). **The first recipe line** may appear on the line after the prerequisites, with a tab character, or **may appear on the same line, with a semicolon**. Either way, the effect is the same.

(Emphasis mine.)

Your example is equivalent to

```
output.o : output.c header1.h header2.h
        header3.h
        gcc output.c -o output.o
```

Answer (score 2):

Semicolon simply allows to write *the first line* of the recipe on the same line as the prerequisites list.

This way (given that your recipes fit a single line) you can write a Makefile w/o any evil tabs. There's no much use in it otherwise.